# Android Toolbar disappear during scrolling with Coordinatorlayout

Tags: android, toolbar

a strange thing happened when I try to implement the toolbar with the `Coordinatorlayout`.

1. everything seems ok when I scroll down and scroll up the `toolbar` show correctly

[image]

2. however after I scroll down to a certain level the screen became

[image]

The XML is below, any idea of it, thanks?

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    />

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski yes.. but the result is not correct after scroll down to certain level the toolbar will disappear and shows a blank view

Comment: Did you try using a `NoActionBar` theme?

Comment: Happens to me too, on pre M only (Compiling 23 support.design 23). I'm using NoActionBar theme. Really Weird.

Ths invisible view trick posted below seems to work (tested on N5 4.4.4)

Answer (score 15):

Place a blank view below your `Toolbar` before the `AppBarLayout` closing statement. It worked for me when I had this problem.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/appbar_bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: This seems to be no longer necessary in the latest support library version (23.0.1). I was using this solution but with 23.0.1 the bug looks like it's been fixed.

Comment: @jguerinet thanks for updating us. Saves everyone a headache. You could add it as an answer to similar questions, and this one, to inform others.

Comment: Omg thank you man, I faced with the same issue on 28.0.2 version, your solution helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using **app:liftOnScroll="false"**.
It worked in my case.